# How is this code derived from the concatenated Walsh-Hadamard Reed-Solomon code?

Tags: error-correcting-codes

### Background

Let $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n < m$. We call $C : \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^m$ an error correcting code of distance $\delta \in [0,1]$ if for any distinct $x^1, x^2 \in \{0,1\}^n$, it is the case that

$$\Delta_C(x_1, x_2) := \frac{|\{i \in [m] : C(x^1)_i \neq C(x^2)_i\}|}{m} \geq \delta$$

The Walsh-Hadamard code $WH : \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{2^n}$ is the error correcting code defined as follows. For $x \in \{0,1\}^n$, $WH(x)$ is the $2^n$ length bit vector $w$ indexed by $y \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, where $w_y := \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot y_i \mod 2$.

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with $m \leq |\mathbb{F}|$. Informally, the Reed-Solomon code $RS : \{0, 1\}^{n\log|\mathbb{F}|} \rightarrow \{0 ,1\}^{m\log|\mathbb{F}|}$ is the code obtained by interpreting the input string as a $\mathbb{F}$ polynomial and evaluating this polynomial on a list of $m$ elements of $\mathbb{F}$. We define this formally as follows. First, define some binary encoding $\langle a \rangle$ for each $a \in \mathbb{F}$. Let $(z_1,z_2...z_m)$ be some list of $m$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}$. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \{0, 1\}^{k \log |\mathbb{F}|}$, let $\overline{x}$ be the $\mathbb{F}^k$ vector such that $\langle \overline{x}_i \rangle = x_ix_{i+1}...x_{i + \log{|\mathbb{F}}|}$, and let $p_x$ be the degree $k - 1$ univariate $\mathbb{F}$ polynomial whose degree $i$ coefficient is $\overline{x}_{i+1}$. Now let $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n \log |\mathbb{F}|}$, and define $RS(x)$ as $w \in \{0,1\}^{m \log |\mathbb{F}|}$ such that $\overline{w}_i = p_x(z_i)$.

We define the concatenated Walsh-Hadamard Reed-Solomon code $WH \circ RS : \{0, 1\}^{n\log|\mathbb{F}|} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{m |\mathbb{F}|}$ as follows. For $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n \log|\mathbb{F}|}$, $WH \circ RS(x)$ is the boolean $m \times |\mathbb{F}|$ matrix $A$ whose $i$th row is

$$WH\left(\left\langle \left(\overline{RS(x)}\right)_i \right\rangle\right)^T$$

Claim 19.14 of Arora-Barak states that $WH \circ RS$ has distance $\frac{1}{2}(1 - \frac{n}{m})$. The book then goes on to say the following:

> Because for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a finite field $\mathbb{F}$ of size in $[k, 2k]$, we can use [the $WH \circ RS$] construction to obtain, for every $n$, a polynomial time computable error correcting code $E : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{20n^2}$ of distance $0.4$.

---

### Question

I understand how $WH \circ RS$ can be computed in polynomial time and has the aforementioned distance, but how did they obtain $E$ with such parameters from $WH \circ RS$?